# Is there a website for drop-in life drawing sessions?

Tags: drawing

I draw people from life whenever and wherever I can. But it's tough to find drop-in life drawing sessions when I'm traveling.

Is there a website or database or mailing list for drop-in life drawing sessions?  If so, what are the characteristics of that resource that make it a good solution?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks after service recommendations.

Comment: Sorry @Joachim, after thinking this over, I think what he is looking for can be seen as a tool, moreso than a service.  I retract my close vote, and am able to also provide an answer...

Comment: I actually agree, in retrospect. Also, there is no mention of anything in particular, just *a* service, a tool, indeed, to help with the drawing.

Comment: Just asking for a list isn't a good fit for a Q&A site because it is very open-ended.  The answers are never "complete", and it can be hard to identify a best answer.  If answers are just links to resources, it doesn't add much value to a simple Google search.  I added a request for supplemental information so that answers can provide context as to why they are good suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

@Kevin, here are the online sites my husband uses to practice figure drawing from home:

- [New Masters Academy](https://www.nma.art/)
- [CroquisCafe on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAZZ8kXStsAD_SJS9LWNdEQ)

Comment: I agree that these kinds of resource recommendations can be appropriate on A&C, while they might not be on most other sites.  But just links aren't great answers (see my edit and comment on the question).  Can you expand the answer to provide more information on each link; what they offer that makes them good solutions?  Thanks.

Comment: @fixer1234: Will do, thanks for the constructive feedback, I get what you are saying.  My husband is the expert on these sites so when he is back from a business trip I will have him help me craft an excellent rewrite...   ~L